# How to determine if Toolpart is running inside SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

A web part can't use certain objects such as Page.Request as detailed in [Best Practice to create designer friendly server controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/10/03/best-practice-to-create-designer-friendly-server-controls.aspx) when running in a designer such as SharePoint Designer.

You can use the [DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.designmode.aspx) property to determine if a web part is running inside a designer and act appropriately.

However this doesn't seem to work for Toolparts - it always returns false.

How do you determine if a Toolpart is running inside SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the [Toolpane.InCustomToolpane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.toolpane.incustomtoolpane.aspx) property

So from the toolpane code its

```
this.ParentToolPane.InCustomToolPane
```

An aside - I think the reason for this difference (though its a poor reason) is that the web part page is loaded into a designer taken from Visual Studio (Whidbey) as mentioned in the msdb blog, but the toolpart is loaded into a browser window.